# I renewed my passport and my Canadian multiple visa is on my old passport, my photo on old passport was damaged by Child

Tags: visas, passports, canada, passport-stamps

I renewed my passport and my multiple Canadian visa is on my old passport, my photo on my old passport was damaged by my child. I have checked that my visa on my old passport still valid. But will the damaged front page (photo) cause some problems?

Comment: sure that it will cause issues. Specially in the front page...